# CSS Right Column Vertical Stacked Not Shows

Tags: html, css

CSS right side column content with image to be stacked vertical. CSS not showing right side columns

```
#stack {
    float:right;
    clear:right;

#rightcolumnTop {
    background-image: "../../images/project-header.jpg"
    margin-top: 0px; 
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: -600px;
    float: left;
    z-index:1;
}

#rightcolumnMiddle {
    background-image: "../../images/wines-header.jpg"
    position:absolute;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: -600px;
    float: left;
    z-index:2;
}
```

JSFiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/y08uw36v/

Comment: Couldn't understand the problem ?

Comment: what are you seeking for? clarify the problem in a clear way

Answer (score 0):

change your color to a darker color, you have #fff

```
body {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
color:#333  <----
```

}

Comment: no problem (: make sure to make it the correct answer @CTOManager

Comment: now my image fills the entire page. I need to constrain the image to the #rightcolumnTop <div> tag; and #rightcolumnMiddle <div>; and #rightcolumnBottom <div> tag

Comment: I'll check it out

Comment: the background-image is not showing from the CSS, is this the best / worse location for attached images to be shown inside a float <div>?

#rightcolumnTop {
    background-image: "../images/project-header.jpg"
 margin-top: 0px; 
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: -600px;
    float: left;
    z-index:1;
}

#rightcolumnMiddle {
    background-image: "../images/wines-header.jpg"
 position:absolute;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: -600px;
    float: left;
 z-index:2;
}

Comment: Depends on where your img is stored.  Jsfiddle might not be the best way to use `background-image:  "your path"` should you can use `background-image: url("whatever you want like")`.  I'm not sure how you want to display your images though?

Comment: The image is for background and the text will be placed up top of image to be clickable for link or open up lower panel for page content. I will move my background image to an URL

Comment: I was able to get the images display on the index.html browser, but the placement of the images is stacked from my <div id="rightcolumnTop"> &  <div id="rightcolumnMiddle">, for example, but now the right side float of the content <div id="rightcolumnTop/Middle"> is now only going below the header / 1st panel <div id="header">, but not on the right side of this <div id="header"> content

Comment: Do you have an image of how you would like for the image to display? It's kind of odd looking if this isn't responsive.

Comment: for image: width: 650px; height: 400px; to show on right side float

Comment: basically, 50% of web page is left panel and 50% is right image stacked panels that serve as links for opening new html page

Comment: see if this is what you're looking for https://jsfiddle.net/y08uw36v/8/

Comment: that looks like a much better float (right side). let me update my jsfiddle thanks

Comment: no problem, if this answer your question.  please make the answer correct.